# Refraction of light from the earths atmosphere

Tags: optics, refraction, atmospheric-science

If a beam of light is propagating through the earths atmosphere is heading towards space, and is moving from a medium with a refractive index of n1 =1.000293 to a medium with a refractive index of n2 = 1 and the angle of incidence is greater than the critical angle. Would the light be reflected back into the earths atmosphere and would a person situated at the air-space interface see their reflection like a mirror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incident ray will be almost parallel to the interface tangent. And thus, TIR ray will be almost grazing the interface as well. He won't be able to see himself but another person facing him can. Though, **TIR can take place,** it doesn't really have a lot of significance here as the refractive indices of the two media are almost the same [image: Reference Image]
Pardon the crude illustration

Side Note: The boundary where atmosphere ends is not concrete, the density of air keeps on decreasing till it becomes 1 (vacuum)